# xstring: replace substring of text defined in macro

Tags: xstring

I'm not sure whether I've got the terminology right in the question title, but here's what I'm looking for.

I'm trying to put together a class file that specifies the formatting requirements my university requires for theses/dissertations. One of the things I'm trying to do as a part of this to set up a command `\abstractheader` that will print the header for the abstract page.

Part of the abstract page lists the candidate's degrees. The formatting requirements of the university are such that the name of each university should be in uppercase. This is easy to ensure with `\MakeUpperCase{}` or `textcase`'s `\MakeTextUppercase{}`.

However, the issue is that when I use either of these commands, it also makes "Ph.D." be printed as "PH.D.", which is incorrect (according to the formatting guidelines). It should remain "Ph.D." What I'd like to do is ensure that the rest of the text is all uppercase, but prevent the string "Ph.D." from being printed in uppercase.

I've tried using `xstring`'s `\StrSubstitute` macro in the definition of my `\alldegrees` command, which users can use to enter information about their degrees, to replace `Ph.D.` with `\NoCaseChange{Ph.D.}`. But when I do this, I get an error about an illegal parameter number in the definition of `\reserved@a` that I can't figure out how to solve.

Another option is of course, to require users to manually specify `\NoCaseChange{Ph.D.}` or just type everything in the required case when they enter their information, but either of those defeats a bit of the purpose of trying to set up a file that implements the formatting requirements in the first place.

The MWE doesn't contain the class file, but the idea is that what's in the preamble would eventually be part of a separate class (with other things as well).

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

% To go in a class file
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{textcase}

\makeatletter
    \def\@alldegrees{}
    \newcommand\alldegrees[1]{%
        %\def\@alldegrees{\StrSubstitute{#1}{Ph.D.}{\NoCaseChange{Ph.D.}}} % produces error
        \def\@alldegrees{#1}
     }

     \newcommand{\partofabstractheader}{ % Real command will have more stuff
         \MakeTextUppercase{\@alldegrees}
      }
\makeatother

% To be defined in user's preamble
\alldegrees{B.A., My Uni1\\
            M.A., My Uni2\\
            Ph.D., My Uni3} % produces: PH.D., MY UNI3

 %\alldegrees{B.A., My Uni1\\
 %            M.A., My Uni2\\
 %            \NoCaseChange{Ph.D.}, MyUni3} % produces Ph.D., MY UNI3; but not as straightforward for end user

  \begin{document}
       \partofabstractheader
  \end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a more robust string replacement.

```
\documentclass{article}

% To go in a class file
\usepackage{textcase}

\makeatletter

\def\@alldegrees{}
\newcommand\alldegrees[1]{%
  \def\@alldegrees{#1}%
  \uncapitalizephd\@alldegrees
}

\newcommand{\partofabstractheader}{ % Real command will have more stuff
  \MakeTextUppercase{\@alldegrees}
}
\makeatother

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new_protected:Npn \uncapitalizephd #1
 {
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { Ph\.D\. } { \c{NoCaseChange}\cB\{Ph.D.\cE\} } #1
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

% To be defined in user's preamble
\alldegrees{B.A., My Uni1\\
            M.A., My Uni2\\
            Ph.D., My Uni3} % produces: PH.D., MY UNI3

\begin{document}

\partofabstractheader

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here, I introduce `\ConditionalTextUppercase` that sets everything with `\MakeUppercase` *except* delimiter-separated string phrases specified in the argument to  `\setsepchar`.  The separator delimiter is `||`.  The macro uses the `listofitems` package to accomplish its work.

In the MWE, I make `Ph.D` and `Mc` as the string phrases on which to defer uppercasing.  More exceptions may be added.

```
\documentclass{article}

% To go in a class file
%\usepackage{xstring}
\input listofitems% or \usepackage{listofitems}
\usepackage{textcase}

\setsepchar{Ph.D.||Mc}

\makeatletter
    \def\@alldegrees{}
    \newcommand\alldegrees[1]{%
        %\def\@alldegrees{\StrSubstitute{#1}{Ph.D.}{\NoCaseChange{Ph.D.}}} % produces error
        \def\@alldegrees{#1}
     }

     \newcommand{\partofabstractheader}{ % Real command will have more stuff
         \ConditionalTextUppercase{\@alldegrees}
      }
\makeatother

\newcommand\ConditionalTextUppercase[1]{%
  \readlist\cuclist{#1}%
  \foreachitem\zz\in\cuclist[]{%
    \ifnum\zzcnt=1 \else\cuclistsep[\zzcnt-1]\fi
    \expandafter\MakeTextUppercase\expandafter{\zz}%
  }
}

% To be defined in user's preamble
\alldegrees{B.A., My Uni1\\
            M.A., McHenry College\\
            Ph.D., My Uni3} % produces: PH.D., MY UNI3

 %\alldegrees{B.A., My Uni1\\
 %            M.A., My Uni2\\
 %            \NoCaseChange{Ph.D.}, MyUni3} % produces Ph.D., MY UNI3; but not as straightforward for end user

  \begin{document}
       \partofabstractheader
  \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I’m disappointed that you didn’t find a way to somehow involve `tokcycle`. `;-)`

Comment: @Gaussler It was my first thought, believe me, but I concluded it would be more difficult, as I would need to search out the exclusion words one token at a time.  But you certainly give me a good idea...build a tokcycle library routine that can test the input stream against a specified string.

Comment: @Gaussler Of course, `listofitems` is also a **great** package.

Comment: Glad I could be of help. `;-)`